# How does this Math.random() code work when used with brackets?

Tags: javascript

What is the order of operation in this code?

Does it start with the brackets, then multiply the result by the value generated by Math.random() then finally it adds the min variable?

```
function randTime(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

Comment: Yes. It works like that.